# how do i match a number with a letter directly after or before

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers, regression

```
const input = "2a smith road ";

const input 2 = "333 flathead lake road, apartment 3b"

const address = input.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s+\w{1})/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
```

Output should look like this:

```js
input = "2A Smith Road"

input = "333 Flathead Lake Road, Apartment 3B"
```

Comment: Doesn’t `/\d[a-zA-Z]/g` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think looking for a word character (`\w`), preceded (`(?<=...)`) by a word boundary (`\b`) and optional digits (`\d*`) should cover all cases:

```js
const input = [
  "2a smith road",
  "333 flathead lake road, apartment 3b"
];

const capitalize = (s) => s.replace(/(?<=\b\d*)(\w)/g, l => l.toUpperCase());

input.forEach(s => console.log(capitalize(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1 or more digits followed by a lower case char `\b\d+[a-z]\b` and uppercase the whole match

```js
[
  "2a smith road",
  "333 flathead lake road, apartment 3b"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/\b\d+[a-z]\b/g, m => m.toUpperCase())));
```